# Firebase configure error even though it's being called in AppDelegate.swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I am getting the following error:

> Must call FIRApp.configure() before using FIRDatabase.

Even though I am calling FIRApp.configure() in my AppDelegate.swift

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was declaring database reference variables as class variables. This was causing the issue. It looks like declaring them inside (or after) viewDidLoad() function is the correct approach.

*Note: I asked and answered this question, as the top link on google when googling this error is a poorly asked closed SO question. (Bear in mind: I'm coming from Android Firebase, and a day into iOS development.)*